# Upgrading to Selenium 3.0.1 Print An Error Message

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I am running the latest versions of chrome and firefox with their latest respective driver.exe. After opening creating a new instance I get this error:

> Nov 04, 2016 7:46:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   Nov 04, 2016 7:46:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

This is bad becuase when I run my regression test suite it gives an unreachable browser exception midway in my tests which skips all of my tests. I can't stay on 3.0.0.beta2 forever.

Sample Code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\path-to webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://mail.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use latest version of Chrome WebDriver (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)? I run success with latest Selenium and latest Google Chrome WebDriver stack.

Comment: @DoNhuVy  I'm using the latest version. What OS version are you using. I have windows 7.

Comment: I use Windows 10 Pro (x64)